# Queue command discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a queue command but these two parts wont work `{0.source.title}` and `{0.source.url}` keep giving me this error

```
embed = (discord.Embed(description=f'**Music Queue ({len(ctx.voice_state.songs)} track)**\n**Now Playing:**\n[{0.source.title}]({0.source.url}) {self.source.duration_left} Left\n{queue}', color = discord.Colour.dark_red())
```

Error:

```
Unexpected token at end of expression Pylance [427, 144]
```

Here is the full code:

```
    @commands.command(name='queue')
    async def _queue(self, ctx: commands.Context, *, page: int = 1):
        """Shows the player's queue.
        You can optionally specify the page to show. Each page contains 10 elements.
        """

        source = self.source

        if len(ctx.voice_state.songs) == 0:
            return await ctx.send('Empty queue.')

        items_per_page = 10
        pages = math.ceil(len(ctx.voice_state.songs) / items_per_page)

        start = (page - 1) * items_per_page
        end = start + items_per_page

        queue = ''
        for i, song in enumerate(ctx.voice_state.songs[start:end], start=start):
            queue += '`{0}` [**{1.source.title}**]({1.source.url})\n'.format(i + 1, song)

        if queue == 1:
            embed = (discord.Embed(description=f'**Music queue ({{len(ctx.voice_state.songs)}} track)**\n**Now Playing:**\n[{0.source.title}]({0.source.url}) {self.source.duration_left} Left\n{queue}', color = discord.Colour.dark_red())
                 .set_footer(text='Viewing page {}/{}'.format(page, pages)))
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            embed = (discord.Embed(description=f'**Music Queue ({len(ctx.voice_state.songs)} tracks)**\n**Now Playing:**\n[{0.source.title}]({0.source.url}) {self.source.duration_left} Left\n{queue}', color = discord.Colour.dark_red())
                 .set_footer(text='Viewing page {}/{}'.format(page, pages)))
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```